# STOMP Websocket sometimes doesn't response

Tags: ios, objective-c, websocket

I have a service using `STOMP` Websocket, I use `WebsocketStompKit` library 
https://github.com/rguldener/WebsocketStompKit

```
NSURL *websocketUrl = [NSURL urlWithString:@"ws://xxx/websocket"];
STOMPClient *client = [[STOMPClient alloc] initWithURL:websocketUrl websocketHeaders:nil useHeartbeat:NO];

[self.client connectWithHeaders:nil completionHandler:^(STOMPFrame *connectedFrame, NSError *error) {
        NSString *status = [Utils getStringIgnoreNull:connectedFrame.command];
        if ([status isEqualToString:@"CONNECTED"]) {
            NSLog(@"-------Connected to socket server!");
            [self subscribe];
        }
    }];
```

I followed the instructions to setup `STOMPClient`, it works ok.
But sometime, it doesn't run to completionHander block, I waited a long time but it still don't response anything. My internet connection is very fine.

So anyone know the solution? Or can you give me another library to do this.

Thank so much.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out in [this](https://github.com/acmacalister/jetfire/issues/52#issuecomment-253112311) and [this](https://github.com/rguldener/WebsocketStompKit/issues/9#issuecomment-253719648) Github issue conversations, the problem was on the server side. If anyone comes here looking for help, I suggest going through these libraries issue pages and trying to match your problem, or contact the creators of [Jetfire](https://github.com/acmacalister/jetfire) and [Starscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/starscream) (if you are implementing them) because they are very friendly and do answer your upgrade/new feature issues pretty quickly!